# Making SqlDataAdapter/Datareader "Really Read-Only"

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, sqldatareader, sqldataadapter

Updated Question: Is there a way to force dataadapter accept only commands which do not include any update/drop/create/delete/insert commands other than verifying the command.text before sending to dataadapter (otherwise throw exception). is there any such built-in functionality provided by dot net in datareader dataadapter or any other?

Note: DataReader returns results it also accepts update query and returns result. (I might be omitting some mistake but I am showing my update command just before executing reader and then show message after its success which is all going fine

Comment: duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4900630/dataadapter-fill-command-prohibit-write-operation

Comment: An alternative option might be to use the DataTable.Load method takes a SqlDataReader so you don't have to do anything other than DataTable.Load(command.ExecuteReader()).

Comment: Also note that you shouldn't rely on just this alone - make sure you appropriately permission the tables for SELECT permission only (`GRANT SELECT ON [Table] TO [User]`). It's possible for someone to type something along the lines of `SELECT * FROM User;DROP TABLE User;` which is technically a sql statement that returns a resultset :-) The SelectCommand property is just there to abstract data loading into the adapter - it doesn't do anything to prevent the wrong sql from being run.

Comment: @John - see my update for the second part. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you search the string for some keywords? Like CREATE,UPDATE, INSERT, DROP or if the query does not start with SELECT? Or is that too flimsy?

You might also want to create a login for this that the application uses that only has read capability. I don't know if the object has that property but you can make the server refuse the transaction.

Comment: Yes that is the option I missed to mention in my question. But I am looking for some technically solid one. Also here i have to use regex which i want to avoid

Comment: Then I would go with route 2. Set up a server login that only has dataReader. Then with Mike's solution have it use this login for the connection string. Then even if they try to transact somthing other than SELECT the server will say no. You can handle that exception accordingly with a trycatch or something.

Comment: What if the user wanted to use stored procedures? It's perfectly possible to pass a stored procedure called GetAllDataUpdates, for example, that selects data but contains the word "Update". Parsing user input is painful :-) You really should apply permissions at the db level to be absolutely sure.

Comment: Better one. After no choice, I have to do this.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is ensure there are no INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statements prepared for the `DataAdapter`. Your code could look something like this:

```
var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM table", "connection string");
```

OR

```
var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM table", sqlConnectionObject);
```

And bam, you have a read-only data adapter.

Answer (score 1):

If you just wanted a DataTable then the following method is short and reduces complexity:

```
public DataTable GetDataForSql(string sql, string connectionString)
{
    using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
        {
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandText = sql;
            connection.Open();          
            using(SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                DataTable data = new DataTable();
                data.Load(reader);
                return data;
            }

        }

    }

}
```

usage:

```
try{
    DataTable results = GetDataForSql("SELECT * FROM Table;", ApplicationSettings["ConnectionString"]);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    //Logging
    //Alert to user that command failed.
}
```

There isn't really a need to use the DataAdapter here - it's not really for what you want. Why even go to the bother of catching exceptions etc if the Update, Delete or Insert commands are used? It's not a great fit for what you want to do.

It's **important** to **note** that the SelectCommand property doesn't do anything special - when the SelectCommand is executed, it will still run whatever command is passed to it - it just [expects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.selectcommand.aspx) a resultset to be returned and if no results are returned then it returns an empty dataset.

This means that (and you should do this anyway) you should **explicitly grant only SELECT permissions** to the tables you want people to be able to query.

**EDIT**

To answer your other question, [SqlDataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w9y9ttex.aspx)'s are `ReadOnly` because they work via a Read-Only firehose style cursor. What this effectively means is:

```
while(reader.Read()) //Reads a row at a time moving forward through the resultset (`cursor`)
{
   //Allowed
   string name = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("name"));
   //Not Allowed - the read only bit means you can't update the results as you move through them
   reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdina("name")) = name;
}
```

It's read only because it doesn't allow you to update the records as you move through them. There is no reason why the sql they execute to get the resultset can't update data though.

Comment: Have You seen my update? Iam using the same but Strangely it is accepting an update query

Comment: @John It's because they all just execute the sql you pass to it. The only sure way to do what you want to do is to restrict permissions at the database level. SqlDataReader and SelectCommand are about returning result sets from sql queries - they don't restrict the query themselves - you have to do that :-)

Comment: For example: `SELECT * FROM Table; UPDATE Table SET Name = 'Stinky';` is a perfectly valid SQL statement that returns results - you can feed that into either a datareader or a SelectCommand.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a read-only requirement, have your TextBox use a connection string that uses an account with only db_datareader permissions on the SQL database.

Otherwise, what's stopping the developer who is consuming your control from just connecting to the database and wreaking havoc using SqlCommand all on their own?